# Use table name and column name as dynamic in linq using entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have written linq as below, here tableName is dynamic as parameter and select all records in table. And also each table have different column name but this column have same data type in each table.

```
 public List<AccidentNotified> GetParticularLookUp(string tableName)
 {
            List<AccidentNotified> ManageLookUpList = new List<AccidentNotified>();
            using (var cases = new ApiRassiEntities())
            {
                var lookupvalues = (from accident in cases.AccidentNotifiedByLUs
                                    select accident );
                ManageLookUpList = lookupvalues.ToList();


            }
            return ManageLookUpList;
 }
```

here i have to use like below method,

```
using (var cases = new ApiRassiEntities())
{
         var lookupvalues = (from accident in cases.[tableName]
                             select accident );
}
```

So please give your suggestion.Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried System.Linq.Dynamic? Install it from NuGet.

Comment: My question is different so please remove this from duplicate @HimBromBeere

Comment: Please clarify what this has to do with the columnname, I don't see it anywhere except the one mention.